# LED supply from 230V AC

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc, ac, transformer

How many LEDs can I supply from my home power supply.
If I make AC to DC the voltage drops too low.I read this article but dont tell the output DC voltage http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-AC-to-DC .

Comment: @PeteKirkham: What are you talking about? It shows the newly-built power supply being used to drive a solid-state relay.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Dave is right.

Comment: How do you even manage to get too low voltage for a LED when you have 230VAC at your disposal? You'll just have to beat the forward voltage which is 2V at most...

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'd read the caption (connect to regulator) and since the packaging and connection and markings are similar to small AC/DC converters that they were trying to connecting it to a converter to get regulation. Should have checked the part number.

Comment: The qualityof questions is droppon must have something to do with how this sote is managed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How many LEDs can I supply from my home power supply?

A typical home in the US or Europe might have a 24 kW supply. (e.g. 120 V x 200 A or 240 V x 100 A)

A small 5mm 2V LED can visibly illuminate at 10 mA. That's 20 mW

24000 / 0.020 = 1200000

Therefore you could have billions of LEDs but only 1.2 million could be illuminated concurrently. You could perhaps increase this number with PWM if brightness isn't too much of an issue.

This assumes no power losses in the conversion and drivers. I'd apply a rule of thumb power-loss factor before placing an order for 1000000 LEDs.

Don't try this in summer.

Comment: You answered his question exactly, I love it!

Answer (score 2):

The forward volt drop of a typical LED is about 2V and typically it will be taking 20mA. If you directly rectified (and smoothed) the AC mains (say 220V AC) in your house and fed it to a string of LEDs wired in series, you'd be able to illuminate about 150 series-wired LEDs per string. Each string would take 20mA (and consume 6 watts) and if you chose powerful enough rectifier diodes you could have many, many strings wired in parallel.

It needs care to set this up AND avoiding AC shocks is paramount of course but, there is no theoretical reason why you shouldn't be taking 100s of watts or even kW of power to light thousands of LEDs. You would also have to ensure that the LEDs were insulated from anyone touching them when powered because this method does not use an isolation transformer.

If you were to attempt this but recognize a little more safety you could have a switch mode power supply providing isolation, current limiting and the ability to drive up to maybe 30 LEDs per string. There are a few chips out there that do this and are quite efficient. Like before if you use more chips you can parallel plenty of strings of LEDs. Here's an example from LT: -

[image]

Here's one that power directly from AC: -

[image]

Comment: In this case I also have to change voltage from AC to DC or have it as it is?

Comment: The chip shown above needs DC - it is the LED driver - this means a SMPS needs to be used before it (or a regular transformer, rectifier and smoothing cap.)

Comment: Any other way to do it without a chip?I didnt understand if I can go from AC to DC and keep the 230V.

Comment: The first part of my answer covers the direct conversion to about 311 VDC from 220V AC - you can do it that way for sure but I wouldn't.

Comment: 311VDC? And the disadvantages of that?

Comment: It's more dangerous than isolated low voltage solutions!!

Comment: What's the safe zone for the DC voltage?

Comment: If I go to 150V DC and break it to 3 strings that would be dangerous to? It would be 50V per string.

Comment: In the EU the safety low voltage absolute limit is 60V. Try looking up SELV?

Comment: More that isolation issues there are other problems, such as LEDs are so sensitive to transient back voltages. And they should drive in constant current mode than constant voltage mode. That's how it creates thermal stability.

Comment: @StandardSandun are you addressing this comment to anyone in particular?

Comment: Sorry, not like that. I just addressing the issue. And mentioning why it can't just rectified and ran on 311VDC rails.

Comment: @StandardSandun Please explain why because I don't see a problem providing the voltage always stays positive and driven with constant current.

Comment: it does need to drive in constant current mode due to LED have a exponential function. 10mV change would rise to 100mA rise. 
And for the second issue, yes I did'nt noticed L1 and L2 on your design. Sorry.

Comment: But again is that L1 and L2 are enough ? I mean on power lines there are huge transients when power systems are on islanding like operation.